# Fade-in, Fade-out of text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a javascript function that makes some text fade in and out.

For example, in a form the submit button would check the validity of the inputs; if they're not valid, a message is displayed for a few seconds.

I only managed to create the fade-in effect, but not fade-out: what is a simple way to implement this?

Code snippets:

CSS for the error messages:

```
#pwd_not_equ{
opacity:0;
transition: opacity 2s;
color:red;
}
```

JS function that checks if two passwords are equal:

```
if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val() && $("#pass1").val().length != 0)  {

        document.getElementById("pwd_not_equ").style.opacity="1";
        return false;

    };
```

Error message itself is a simple p:

```
<p id="pwd_not_equ"> Passwords must be equal! </p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to recreate the wheel, there are built in jquery functions that do this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little example, I hope it can help you! I am using jQuery on this one, but if its a problem for you, tell me and I will make one with pure javascript.

```js
$('.fadeout').click(function() {
    $('#target').fadeOut('normal');
});

$('.fadein').click(function() {
    $('#target').fadeIn('normal');
});

$('.fd-to').click(function() {
    $('#target').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});

$('.fd-to1').click(function() {
    $('#target').fadeTo(1000, 1);
});
```

```css
body {padding:30px;}

#target {
  background:#dfabba;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  height:200px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- fadeIn, fadeOut dan fadeTo -->
<button class="fadeout">FadeOut!</button>
<button class="fadein">FadeIN!</button>
<button class="fd-to">FadeTo 0.5</button>
<button class="fd-to1">Reset</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you already have jQuery you might as well use the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods:

```
$(element).fadeIn();
$(element).fadeOut();
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the opacity to 0 in any of your code, this will work:

```
$('#pass1, #pass2').change(function() {
   if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val() && $("#pass1").val().length != 0)  {
       $("#pwd_not_equ").css('opacity','1');
   } else $("#pwd_not_equ").css('opacity','0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery also has toggle

http://jsfiddle.net/bdellinger/ukyvpsbf/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $( "#pwd_not_equ" ).toggle('slow');   
});
```